# How to read from multiple file into multiple matrices in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am new to python and to programming. I have two files to be opened and the text filtered. Till here I am able to do. But after that, now i need to store these results in two different 2d matrices (ie. list of list) for further calculations. Which I am not able to achieve.
I have got so far.

```
     import numpy as np
     import fileinput


     def main():
        file= []
        maxLengthList = 2
        while len(file) < maxLengthList:
            item = raw_input("Enter the path of your file:")
            file.append(item)

       for fileName in file:
          fin = open( fileName,'r')
          for line in fin:
          list = line.split()
          id = list[0]
          if id == 'ATOM':
             type = list[2]
             if type == 'CA':
                position = list[6:9]
                print position



      if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: your question is vague, can you add some sample input and desired output

Comment: My input looks like this:
ATOM    739  N   ASN A  97      21.669  21.285  27.884  1.00 11.40           N
ATOM    740  CA  ASN A  97      22.406  21.167  26.629  1.00 11.45           C
ATOM    741  C   ASN A  97      22.158  19.810  25.954  1.00 10.75           C
ATOM    742  O   ASN A  97      22.093  19.745  24.723  1.00 10.14           O

and my output now is:
['14.598', '12.338', '8.220']
['11.813', '10.492', '10.017']
['11.439', '6.883', '8.768']
['7.979', '5.560', '9.681']

Comment: still vague, cant find out what you are expecting

Comment: I want to store the results in two different matrices. I have two different such files.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are looking for but this may help you

```
matrices= []
maxLengthList = 2
for i in xrange(0, maxLengthList):
    item = raw_input("Enter the path of your file:")
    fin = open( item ,'r')
    # do your stuffs with the file
    after_process = ["your result list"]
    matrices[i] = after_process
```

matrices[0] and matrices[1] have the processed values from your file1 and file2